# Can i restrict to user, videos will save only in internal memory in Android programmatically

Tags: android

In My app there is one feature to capture video and after successfully uploaded on server video will be deleted from phone memory.

I want to use only internal memory to save video.

Can i restrict user through app they can use only internal memory.

What i have done so far.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            videoUri = data.getData();
            try {
                filePath=getFilePath(getActivity(),videoUri);
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            file=new File(filePath);
            Log.e("before compression",file.getAbsolutePath()+"");

            new VideoCompressor().execute();

        }
    }

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getFilePath(Context context, Uri uri) throws URISyntaxException {
        String selection = null;
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        // Uri is different in versions after KITKAT (Android 4.4), we need to
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context.getApplicationContext(), uri)) {
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
            } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }
                selection = "_id=?";
                selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };
            }
        }
        if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            String[] projection = {
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
            };
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                        .query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    return cursor.getString(column_index);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
```

Here i am getting filepath like 
/storage/6638-3139/DCIM/Camera/20180502_125532.mp4(When sd card is present in a phone)
/storage/emulated/0/20180502_125532.mp4(When no sdcard is present in a phone)

Now i want to save this video only in internal memory (Sd card present or not).

Comment: you can record video inside your app, not using default camera app. This way you can store it wherever you want.

Comment: see this official document for getting internal storage file path https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android if Your app's internal storage directory is specified by your app's package name in a special location of the Android file system that can be accessed with the following APIs.
When saving a file to internal storage, you can acquire the appropriate

**directory as a File by calling one of two methods:**

**getFilesDir()**
Returns a File representing an internal directory for your app.
**getCacheDir()**
Returns a File representing an internal directory for your app's temporary cache files. Be sure to delete each file once it is no longer needed and implement a reasonable size limit for the amount of memory you use at any given time, such as 1MB.

you can call **`openFileOutput()`** to get a FileOutputStream that writes to a file in your internal directory. For example, here's how to write some text to a file:

```
 String filename = "myfile";
String outputString = "Hello world!";

try {
    FileOutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    outputStream.write(outputString.getBytes());
    outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    FileInputStream inputStream = openFileInput(filename);
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        total.append(line);
    }
    r.close();
    inputStream.close();
    Log.d("File", "File contents: " + total);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

for more information please check [Save files on device storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#java)

Comment: When i capture 1 video then that time i am getting uri after that i need filepath . How to use above code for uri. how i am getting filepath? can u explain lil bit.